# In Spark, if I partition by a less granular column and then join/groupBy/partitionBy a more granular column will I see performance improvement?

Tags: apache-spark, partitioning

I have a data frame of airline flights. Each flight has a carrier code (i.e. airline id) and a plane tail number. Carrier code to plane tail number is one to many (i.e. carriers can have many planes but each plane only flies for one carrier). There are thousands of plane tail numbers so it would be unwise to partition on that column, but there are only about a dozen carriers. If I partition on the carrier code will it speed up the join/groupBy/partitionBy operations on the tail number? Is there any way to tell spark that a shuffle is not necessary? Or at the very least will spark not have to move data between partitions?

I cannot find a similar question, perhaps because I am not sure how to describe the situation properly.

Comment: If you try to perform join/aggregation/window on a tail number column, Spark will repartition dataframe by this column into `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` anyways .

Comment: Understood, so there will be no speed up

Comment: Yes, your partitioning by carrier code will be basically useless.